# FlatBuffers: object serialization must not be nested

Tags: java, flatbuffers

I am creating a flatbuffer like this:

```
FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder(1);

    SaveSchema.startLogin(fbb);

    SaveSchema.addEmail(fbb, fbb.createString("EMAILCHE"));

    int offset = SaveSchema.endLogin(fbb);

    SaveSchema.finishLoginBuffer(fbb, offset);
```

**My schema:**

```
namespace Objects;


    table Login {
      email:string;
      password:string;
    }

    root_type Login;
    file_identifier "LOGN";
```

I receive the following error:

> FlatBuffers: object serialization must not be nested

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: Following error: FlatBuffers: object serialization must not be nested